# How To Add 2 values in a dictionary together if the key is duplicated?

Tags: python-3.x, list, file, dictionary

So I have this project where it asks the user for the number of .txt files these files are titled 'day' and then the number in ascending order. The format of what's inside the code is a sport/activity(key) then a comma and the number of people doing the sport(value). What I want is it to give an output of all the sports from the text files and if the activity(key) is duplicated then it adds up the people doing it(value). And to top that all off I wanted the total people who were participating(all the values added together)

```
days = int(input("How many days of records do you have? "))
i = 0
list1 = []
d = {}
for i in range(days):
  i += 1
  file = 'day' + str(i)
  f = open(file + '.txt')
  a = []
  for line in f:
    line = line.replace(',' , ' ')
    list1.append(line)
    words = line.split()
    d[words[0]] = words[1]
    a.append[words[1]] 
  stripped_line = [s.rstrip() for s in d]
for key,value in d.items() :
   print (key + "," + value)
print("In total:", a, "attendees.")
```

***INPUT***

```
User_input = 3
```

**day1.txt**

```
swimming,1000
fencing,200
athletics,600
gymnastics,1200
tennis,500
```

**day2.txt**

```
diving,600
swimming,1200
tennis,500
rugby,900
handball,500
hockey,2300
trampoline,200
```

**day3.txt**

```
swimming,400
gymnastics,1200
fencing,100
diving,400
tennis,600
rugby,600
```

***EXPECTED OUTPUT***

```
swimming: 2600
fencing: 300
athletics: 600
gymnastics: 2400
tennis: 1600
diving: 1000
rugby: 1500
handball: 500
hockey: 2300
trampoline: 200
In total: 13000 attendees.
```

***CURRENT OUTPUT***

```
swimming,400
fencing,100
athletics,600
gymnastics,1200
tennis,600
diving,400
rugby,600
handball,500
hockey,2300
trampoline,200
```

Comment: Sorry if it's unclear and not formatted properly I am new to stack

Comment: And if you are wondering why I have a list there that was me trying to do it with a list and then realising I needed a dictionary and i was too lazy to delete the access code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one approach using `collections.defaultdict`.

**Ex:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

days = int(input("How many days of records do you have? "))

result = defaultdict(int)
for i in range(days):
    with open("day{}.txt".format(i)) as infile:
        for line in infile:
            key, value = line.strip().split(",")
            result[key] += int(value)

for key,value in result.items():
    print (key + "," + str(value))

print("In total: {} attendees.".format(sum(result.values())))
```

Comment: with open("day{}.txt".format(i)) as infile:                                                                                 This code checks 'day0.txt but the file names start from 'day1.txt'

Comment: use `for i in range(1, days+1):`

Comment: print(key + "," + value)                                                                                                            TypeError: must be str, not int

Comment: its actually `print (key + "," + str(value))`

Comment: sorry for constantly bugging you but now it gave double the answer

Comment: that's really strange

Comment: try making 3 files with swimming ,1000

Comment: Are you using the code exactly as above? Try adding `print` to see which text file is opened and a print on the line

Comment: Sorry, it was really late at night and I couldn't understand anything lol but after waking up today it worked! thanks for cooperating with my tiny head